# Merge [gestures] into [gesture]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There is a tag [gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gesture) (1116 tagged). Its wiki is

> A gesture is a specific pattern of touch or cursor user input that may be recognized by an application to perform a specific task.

There is a tag [gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gestures) (406 tagged). Its wiki is

> The tag refers to a method of interaction with graphical user interface. Instead of simply choosing, user may draw a shape (so called gesture) over an item, which is recognized by the software and triggers specific reaction. Gestures are very popular, but not limited to touchscreen applications.

Each tag wiki says nearly the same thing: touch or cursor pattern to trigger an event. Of these ~1500 questions, [only 22 are tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gesture+gestures).

I propose that gestures is merged into gesture. I have already updated the tag wiki, <strike>which is pending peer-review</strike> which has [been approved](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6380217/3).

> A gesture is a specific pattern of touch, cursor, or physical movement (Recognized through a camera or other sensor such as [kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kinect) or [leap-motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leap-motion)) that may be recognized by an application to perform a specific task. See also [gesture-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gesture-recognition).

Comment: I concur with the merge (presuming tag is kept), although I am not sure about the wiki. This tag could theoretically encompass non-touch/cursor gestures, e.g. motion tracked or other interesting input devices. I prefer something similar to the second wiki.

Comment: @JasonC Updated. I submitted an edit for [tag:gesture].

Comment: I suggest using the tag synonyms proposal in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gesture/synonyms . It is there but I think hardly anybody uses it.

Comment: @fedorqui I have nothing against that method, but I, among many others, do not have 5 score in said tag.

Comment: Yes, I perfectly understand it. That is supposed to be "the" tool to handle the synonyms, but the way it works makes it be quite unuseful.

Comment: It seems that both tags are lacking super active users, but maybe some of them can be contacted to work together and establish the synonym?

Comment: [Same at stack-exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221034/plural-tag-gestures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like these were synonymized at some point.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gesture/synonyms

Comment: That's why the question was tagged [status-completed].

Comment: @double-beep The mod who did that didn't leave an answer such that the question could be deemed resolved.